The remote repository could not be accessed Make sure a valid repository exists at the specified location and that the correct credentials have been
When I want to download package dependencies with any package (in this case https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-XCFramework),

I'm encountering an issue when trying to access a remote repository. The error message I receive is (I'm on Xcode 16.0 and Sequoia 15.0 (24A335) :
"The remote repository could not be accessed.
Make sure a valid repository exists at the specified location and that the correct credentials have been supplied."
Could anyone help me understand how to resolve this issue?

